# Split string lines and make a data frame

Tags: r, string

I have a small data from a text file read via `readLines`. The file had characters like `#` and I think that is the reason read.table was unable to read it. Here is the first five lines dput:

```
files<-c("\trfinal\t\t", "eq1\t\t\t", "0.ster6\t1.00\t(1.00,1.00)\t.", 
     "1.ster6\t0.65\t(0.47,0.88)\t0.006", "0.parkinson\t1.00\t(1.00,1.00)\t.", 
     "1.ster6#0.parkinson\t1.00\t(1.00,1.00)\t.")
```

`\t` means white space between strings. I would like to split this text lines and put them into a 4 column grid (data frame).

I tried `strsplit(files, "[\\t]")` but it doesn't really do the trick. Any help ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable the treatment of `#` as the `comment.char` in `read.table`:

```
read.table(text=files, sep='\t', comment.char="")
#                    V1     V2          V3    V4
# 1                     rfinal
# 2                 eq1
# 3             0.ster6   1.00 (1.00,1.00)     .
# 4             1.ster6   0.65 (0.47,0.88) 0.006
# 5         0.parkinson   1.00 (1.00,1.00)     .
# 6 1.ster6#0.parkinson   1.00 (1.00,1.00)     .
```

Comment: I think it would be better for them to fix the problem at the source (+1) but their desired output remains somewhat unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you. Both solutions worked nicely.

Answer (score 7):

If the `"\t"` just represents a tab delimiter, try `read.delim`:

```
read.delim(text = files)
#                     X rfinal         X.1   X.2
# 1                 eq1     NA                  
# 2             0.ster6   1.00 (1.00,1.00)     .
# 3             1.ster6   0.65 (0.47,0.88) 0.006
# 4         0.parkinson   1.00 (1.00,1.00)     .
# 5 1.ster6#0.parkinson   1.00 (1.00,1.00)     .
```

You can also consider the `stringi` package. Here, I've treated the `"\t"` as a fixed pattern:

```
library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(files, "\t", simplify = TRUE)
#      [,1]                  [,2]     [,3]          [,4]   
# [1,] ""                    "rfinal" ""            ""     
# [2,] "eq1"                 ""       ""            ""     
# [3,] "0.ster6"             "1.00"   "(1.00,1.00)" "."    
# [4,] "1.ster6"             "0.65"   "(0.47,0.88)" "0.006"
# [5,] "0.parkinson"         "1.00"   "(1.00,1.00)" "."    
# [6,] "1.ster6#0.parkinson" "1.00"   "(1.00,1.00)" "."
```

Overall, though, it's not clear what is supposed to be treated as a header and so on, and it would be better to implement @musically_ut's suggestion about using `comment.char` and trying to resolve the issue at the source.